# CSS files which installed with npm in node_modules folder not found when deploy on Heroku - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am using Rails 5 and `npm` for serving assets.
I installed `Custombox` and `Tooltipster`:

`npm install -save tooltipster`

Same for Custombox.
When I am working on `localhost` everything works fine (all files are there), but when I deploy on Heroku with `git push heroku master` - the CSS files for all what I installed with NPM (in `node_modules` folder) can't be found. I see in the network console - 404 error, not found for these files.

This is my `application.scss` file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'tooltipster.css';
@import 'custombox.css';
```

The CSS files are stored in:

`node_modules/custombox/dist/custombox.css`
and `node_modules/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.main.css`.
If I use `@import tooltipster.main.css` it doesn't found and in on localhost.

This is `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

This is `config/environtments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Before deploy I do - `rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put all the path with .css?

```
 @import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';
 @import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```